# Visual Studio : Rename a folder and adapt namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

In Visual Studio, I have a project with this folders/files

```
Demo.Api.csproj
Program.cs
V1\
  Controllers\
    BarsController.cs
    FoosController.cs
  Models\
    Bar.cs
    Foo.cs
```

I rename the folder "V1" to "V2" and Visual Studio adapt automatically the namespace. **Have you a trick to do this?**

---

When a folder/file is moved, Visual Studio adapt the namespace. So, I create a folder "V2" and move manually sub-folder/file.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to say that you *want* VS to change the namespace, but it doesn't actually do so? (Currently it sounds like you're asserting that it *does* this already...)

Comment: I found this, it may help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/sync-namespace-and-folder-name?view=vs-2022

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, I will try to improve the question. In resume, when a folder is moved, VS adapt the namespace. But when a folder is renamed, the namespace is unchanged.

Comment: @Ghassen Rosalyn can adapt the namespace of 1 file according to the path. It's work fine, but it need to be executed in each files... The same for a project/folder will be perfect.

Comment: @vernou yes i know i did not found such automatic change but you have at least this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Backup your codebase
2. Right click on the solution or the project, then choose **Sync Namespaces**

---

An alternative method:

2. Analyze > Code Cleanup > Configure Code Cleanup
3. Choose a profile, move **Apply namespace matches folder preferences** from the available fixers list to the included fixers list.
4. (Optional) Remove fixers that you don't want to apply.
5. Now if you want to apply these fixers on the whole solution, run "Run Code Cleanup (Profile X) on Solution" from the menu, or run it from the context menu of the project/solution.

Comment: Don't work when files are duplicated. But it's a nice tip to usual case.

Comment: You duplicated a folder? You can exclude that original folder first, sync namespaces, add the folder back by editing the project file. This is based on analysis so you have to fix the confliction first.

Comment: @vernou could you please accept this answer ?

Comment: @Ghassen Of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the VS Find facility to find and replace specific text patterns; use the search folder feature to filter across file types.
This way, you can just work in file system mode without context of a particular project